# Pythonのiterable

Tags: python

Pythonの勉強を始めた初心者です。Pythonのfor文ではinの後ろにはiterableオブジェクトを書けとの説明があります。しかしiterableではないset型がinの後ろに書けてしまいます。またfrozensetを生成するfrozen関数も引数はiterableとなっているのにset型でも生成できてしまいます。どのように考えたらよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 7):

`set`型、及び`frozenset`型は`iterable`です。以下のコードでTrueを表示するようなオブジェクトは`iterable`であるといえます。

```
s = set()
try:
    iterator = iter(s)
    print(True)
except TypeError as e:
    print(False)
```

`iterable` について [用語集 — Python 3.7.2 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)
`iter`について [組み込み関数 — Python 3.7.2 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#iter)

Comment: 素早いご回答ありがとうございます。setはシーケンス型ではないがイテラブルなのですね。setがイテラブルの例に出てこないので、イテラブルではないと思ってしまいました。